# How to trigger a method at page load in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

How can I trigger a method at page load like tab?
for example:

```html
<div id='wraper'>
<!-- div id menu not load -->
<div id="menu">
  <a href='#'>test</a>
  <a href='#'>test</a>
  <a href='#'>test</a>
</div>

<!-- load this content  -->
<div id="content">
konten
</div>
  
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What's the "method" you're trying to run? I don't know what vue.js is, but JavaScript has the built-in `window.onload` event to have code that executes when the page loads. (just google "window.onload" for info)

Comment: I'm trying to make it so when I click on a link in a HTML page, it dynamically loads the requested page into a div with jQuery.

How can I do that?

Comment: Ah, okay! If you're trying to load an entire web page inside another page, that sounds like you'll want to use something called **iframes** (google them). Basically, you'll have an iframe, and it'll have a name (let's suppose you name it "my_iframe"). Then, in your `a` tags, you'll add `target="my_iframe"`, and they will automatically open in the iframe.

Comment: yah like that but  give me example for that

Answer (score 68):

For vue >= 2.0
use `mounted` and for  previous version use `ready`.

```
vm=new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  mounted:function(){
        this.method1() //method1 will execute at pageload
  },
  methods:{
        method1:function(){
              /* your logic */
        }
     },
})
```

Comment: Its better to use `created()` if you are not going use DOM access, as its run earlier in the process, and if you do remote api calls, they are executed earlier

Comment: @Ferrybig true, however - in this instance, it looks like the OP is working with the DOM.

Answer (score 22):

This syntax is working fine:

```
export default {
    mounted() {
      this.myMethod();
    },
    methods: {
      myMethod() {
        return 'hello world!';
      }
    },
}
```